# True or False: If the graph of a function is a submanifold, then $f$ is differentiable.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I am asked to prove the following:

"Show that if $f$ is differentiable, then the graph of $f$ is an $n$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$. Does the converse hold?"

I have proved the statement. Now I am faced with the converse. My first thought was: "No, the converse does not hold." And to demonstrate a counterexample, I should pick a continuous function with a cusp like $y = |x|$. But while $|x|$ is a manifold, my understanding is that it is not a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$. So now I am not sure. On the other hand, I have found many proofs of the forward direction only; I assume if the converse were also true then these proofs would be iff-style proofs.

If the converse is false, any hints about a counterexample would be much appreciated! I can work out the details.

---

(Note, the definition of submanifold we are using in this class is as follows: A subset $M^n \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ is an $n$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ of class $C^p$ if, for all $x \in M^n$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and a $C^p$ submersion $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ and $U \cap M = f^{-1}(0)$.)

Comment: The graph of $f(x)=|x|$ is a mannifold, but not a differentiable mannifold. No nhbd of the cusp is, diffeomorphic to an open intervall.

Comment: @user940347, that's not quite correct. The graph $y=|x|$ is a smooth manifold, but it is not a smooth submanifold.

Comment: Why  don’t you look at $y=x^{1/3}$ ?

Comment: HINT: The issue is whether projection of the submanifold to $\Bbb R^n$ has rank $n$ everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example is already suggested in the comments: consider the graph

$$S= \{ (x, x^{1/3}) \in \mathbb R^2: \ x\in \mathbb R\}.$$

First of all, $S$ is a $1$-submanifold in $\mathbb R^2$ since

$$S= \{ (y^3, y)  \in \mathbb R^2: \ y\in \mathbb R\}$$
and $y\mapsto y^3$ is smooth. However $x\mapsto x^{1/3}$ is not smooth, so the converse does not hold.